# Typescript generics - one of subclasses claimed to not have inherited properties?

Tags: typescript, generics

Today I getting an error I can not solve for few hours already, even in a small personal project.
I was trying to implement a generic repositories thing, a very basic one.
Here are few classes:
**Base Entity class:**

```js
import {EntityType, Fields} from "./decorators";
import {IEntity} from "./validation-interfaces";
import {applyProperties} from "./validation-core";

@EntityType()
export class Entity implements IEntity {
    //used only by db impl
    public _id:any;
    @Fields.String(true)
    key: string;
    @Fields.String(true)
    name: string;
    @Fields.String()
    organizationId?:string;
    @Fields.String()
    ownerKey?:string;
    @Fields.DateTime(true)
    createdAt: Date;
    @Fields.String(true)
    createdBy:string;
    @Fields.DateTime(false, null)
    lastUpdatedAt: Date;
    @Fields.String(false, null)
    lastUpdatedBy: string;
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    recycled: boolean;
    @Fields.DateTime(false, null)
    lastRecycledAt?:Date;
    @Fields.String(false, null)
    lastRecycledBy?:string;

    @Fields.DateTime(false, null)
    lastRestoredAt?:Date;
    @Fields.String(false, null)
    lastRestoredBy?:string;

    constructor(props:Partial<Entity>) {
        this._id = props._id;
        applyProperties(Entity, props, this);
    }

}
```

**An Organization class:**

```js
@EntityType()
export class Organization extends Entity {
    @Fields.String(true)
    companyName = "";
    @Fields.String(true)
    companyRegistrationCountryCode = "";
    @Fields.String(true)
    companyGovId = "";
    @Fields.String()
    websiteUrl = "";
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    billingAddressInDifferentCountry = false;
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    useDifferentEmailForInvoices = false;
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    useDifferentContactPersonForInvoices = false;
    @Fields.ObjectOf(AddressDetails, true, new AddressDetails({}))
    billingAddress = new AddressDetails({});

    constructor(props:Partial<Organization>) {
        super(props);
        applyProperties(Organization, props, this);
    }
}
```

**An email message class:**

```js
import {EntityType, Fields} from "../validation/decorators";

let {Entity, applyProperties} = require('../validation');

@EntityType()
export class EmailMessageParameters {
    [name:string]:any;
    constructor(values:any) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}

@EntityType("email-messages", 'eml')
export class EmailMessage extends Entity {
    @Fields.String(true)
    templateId: string;
    @Fields.ObjectOf(EmailMessageParameters, true, new EmailMessageParameters({}))
    parameters:any;
    @Fields.String(true)
    email:string;
    @Fields.String(true)
    displayName: string;
    @Fields.String(true)
    provider: string;
    @Fields.String(false, null)
    deliveryId: string;
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    sent: boolean;
    @Fields.Boolean(false, false)
    failed:boolean;
    @Fields.String(false, null)
    errorMessage:string;
    constructor(props:Partial<EmailMessage>) {
        super(props);
        applyProperties(EmailMessage, props, this);
    }
}
```

And the repo factory function:

```js
let reposMap = new Map<string, any>();

export type EntityConstructor<T extends Entity> = { new (props:Partial<T>):T};

export function getRepository<T extends Entity>(ctr: EntityConstructor<T>):Repository<T> {
    let validator = getValidatorForConstructor(ctr, true);
    let rep = reposMap.get(validator.id) as Repository<T>;
    if (!rep) {
        rep = new Repository<T>(ctr, validator.storageName, validator.idPrefix, validator.idStrength || 32);
        reposMap.set(validator.id, rep);
    }
    return rep;
}
```

The line that works:

```js
let organizations = getRepository(Organization);
```

And the line that drives me mad:

```js
let emailMessages = getRepository(EmailMessage);
```

because of an absurd error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof EmailMessage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntityConstructor<Entity>'.
Types of construct signatures are incompatible.<br/>Type 'new (props: Partial<EmailMessage>) => EmailMessage' is not assignable to type 'new (props: Partial<Entity>) => Entity'.
Type 'EmailMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'Entity': _id, key, name, createdAt, and 4 more.
```

The explicit variant like

```js
let messagesRepository = getRepository<EmailMessage>(EmailMessage);
```

causes other error:

```
TS2344: Type 'EmailMessage' does not satisfy the constraint 'Entity'.
Type 'EmailMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'Entity': _id, key, name, createdAt, and 4 more.
```

Remember that EmailMessage is subclass of Entity?

Restarting Webstorm with  clearing caches does not help.

The typescript setup is located at `/src/tsconfig.json` to affect only contents in `src` and the contents for browser are webpack-ed in other folder `static` where own `src` exists for `ts-loader`.
Contents of `/src/tsconfig.json` is following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../build"
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.*"],
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

The mentioned decorators are pure in sense they do not override constructor, do not define property descriptors, etc. Just some metadata aggregation to be used in some code like repositories impl and form generation.

Thanks for your time and for reading my long post.

Comment: pls provide minimum reproducible example, I mean, really minimum

Comment: I was in a hurry, so I just have a pieces of real code where problem happen. I will post workaround in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround ahead:

I was able to getting a working version of this approach.
What I changed:

1. removed all advanced constraints from `Repository<T>`, `getRepository<T>()` like `extends Entity`.
2. replaced the

```
type EntityConstructor<T extends Entity> = {new (props:Partial<T>) => T};
```

with simpler

```
type ConstructorFunction<T> = {new():T}
```

and than it finally compiled and worked.
Of course, I had to add some extra checks like if validator details about table and key format missing, throw error on try to create the repo for it.
This is not so fancy as allowing calling the `getRepository<T>(ctr:ConstructorFunction<T>):Repository<T>` only if T extends `Entity` class, but actually, it is possible to forget to specify table name in related `EntityType` call, so that safeguard is better anyway.

BTW I still was able to send the parameters to constructor (that Partial value) anyway.